# PHP: send post to div on same page instead of another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page called login.php loaded into a div on another page (index.php). login.php includes a form with action pointing to login.php

Once I press the submit button, the page will open either in a new tab (if no target is specified), or as the whole page (if target is _top, overwriting index.php). what I want is to have index.php open while login.php is loaded into it's div, and the post data to go to login.php which is inside the div. is that even possible?

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="others.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require_once('funcs.php');
    if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) 
    {
        $username=cleanInput($_POST['user']);
        $password=cleanInput($_POST['pass']);
        if (login($username,$password)) { show_login_form("Invalid username or password!"); }
        else 
        {
            // login...
            echo "okay boss!";
        }
    }
    else { show_login_form(null); }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**FUNCS.PHP**

```
<?php

function cleanInput($data)
{
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    return $data;
}

function show_login_form($err)
{
    echo '<h4>Enter username and password:</h4>';
    if (isset($err)) { echo "<span style='color:red'>Error: $err</span><br>"; }
    echo '
        <br><form method="post" action="login.php"> 
        username: <br><input name="user" type="text"><br> 
        password: <br><input name="pass" type="password"><br><br>
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Login"></form>
    ';
}
?>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Dating Site</title>
      <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php require_once ("header.php"); ?>
    <div id="mainframe" class="mainframe">
        <?php require_once ("home.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <?php require_once ("footer.php"); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

and to load a page into the "mainframe" div,I use this code:

```
function loadsel(page)
    {   
        if (page == 1)
            $("div#mainframe").load('login.php');
    }
```

Comment: ^-- http://www.ondeweb.in/ajax-login-form-with-jquery-and-php @sємsєм your link formatting contains `]` which will result in an error. Just saying. Am sure you meant [this tutorial](http://www.ondeweb.in/ajax-login-form-with-jquery-and-php) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- :) You are talking about AJAX login form. You can use this tutorial http://www.ondeweb.in/ajax-login-form-with-jquery-and-php/ or search for "ajax login form" on this website.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use ajax to submit your form . Try this plugin and add the following code

```
   http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit
```

download the plugin

```
   function login(){
      $('#login_form').ajaxSubmit({

    target:'#output_login',
    url:'./php/login.php'


   });
  return false;

}
```